# Contact analysis does not converge due to the projection falls outside valid domain

Tags: finite-element, numerics

I implemented Node-To-Surface contact algorithm (*Wriggers, Peter*, [**Computational contact mechanics.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-32609-0), Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-32608-1/hbk). xii, 518 p. (2006). [ZBL1104.74002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1104.74002).). The code is done by first forming the contact element, comprising of a slave node on the ball and a master line of the base. In the example of a ball penetrating into a soft block, the simulation could run until a point that the projection within a contact element falls outside the corresponding master in the Newton-Raphson iteration. Subsequently, the implicit NR loop does not converge anymore. Does anyone have experience dealing with this issue?

This is the snapshot of the system before failing
[image: The system before failing]

This is the issue, noted the black circle, the slave node (blue) located close to one of the master nodes (purple), leading to the issue above.

[image]

Comment: Does it come from an open source code or commercial software? Either way, please indicate it in your question, which might help people to understand what's going on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is in-house code. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Well then you have to solve it in-house if you want to keep as much detail from us as possible.

Comment: Well, it's much unclear now when you say in-house... Is it an open source code publicly available somewhere like Github? If no, so why you think we are magician that can guess what's wrong with your "in-house" code...

Comment: Perhaps problem is how you calculate distance is non-smooth function at that point. Look at gap function.

Comment: @likask the gap function is fine. The linearization is perfect when the projection is inside the master segment. Problem happens only when slave node approaches master node.

Comment: I think you’ve got some problematic terms in your post and  should consider some edits: https://www.acm.org/diversity-inclusion/words-matter.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest using a different terminology for denoting the relationship between the nodes. An edit would be welcomed here.

Comment: @AntonMenshov well, the slave node and master segment (line of 2 nodes on master side) is the standard terminology in computational contact mechanics. I do not know which term is more correct than this.

Comment: What exactly are the contact condition and criteria?

Comment: The contact condition is gap>=0, contact_pressure<=0, gap*contact_pressure=0